# Remove optional zero from phone number using regex, java

Tags: java, android, regex, phone-number

I've got a java class (called `PhoneNumber`) to validate & process phone numbers.

I've written the last method (to remove the optional zero) myself, but I'd like it to be a little more straightforward (possibly with a regex to recognize the optional zero AND to remove it with that same regex, just like `OPTIONAL_PHONE_NUMBER_CHARACTERS` part). This piece of code feels fragile and not 100% correct, even though I think it does what I need and covers all unittests I could think of.

Can anyone give me a clear example that includes a proper regex? (other simple solutions are also welcome).

```
private static final Pattern VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\+?[0-9#*]{1,20}");
private static final Pattern OPTIONAL_PHONE_NUMBER_CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile("[\\s()/.-]");

public static boolean isValid(String phoneNumber)
{
    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    String compactPhoneNumber = removeOptionalCharacters(phoneNumber);
    return VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX.matcher(compactPhoneNumber).matches();
}

public static String removeOptionalCharacters(String phoneNumber)
{
    String phoneNumberWithoutOptionalZero = removeOptionalZero(phoneNumber);
    return OPTIONAL_PHONE_NUMBER_CHARACTERS.matcher(phoneNumberWithoutOptionalZero).replaceAll("");
}

private static final String OPTIONAL_ZERO = "(0)";
private static final String OPTIONAL_ZERO_SPLIT_REGEX = Pattern.quote("(0");

public static String removeOptionalZero(String phoneNumber)
{
    String[] split = phoneNumber.split(OPTIONAL_ZERO_REGEX);
    if (split.length == 2 && !split[0].isEmpty())
    {
        return phoneNumber.replaceAll(OPTIONAL_ZERO, "");
    }
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

As you can see, I've extracted the code for removing optional characters in case I need to use the phone number to make a phone call. eg. `+31 12-3456-789` Will turn into `+31123456789`.

The conversions I'd like to work using the method `removeOptionalCharacters` are these:

```
+31 (0)12 3456 789   >   +31123456789
+31 (012) 3456 789   >   +31123456789
(0)12 3456 789       >   0123456789
(012) 3456 789       >   0123456789
```

To round it up, these are the unittests that should succeed:

```
@Test
public void removeOptionalCharacters_HooksAroundOptionalZero_ZeroIsRemoved()
{
    String compactPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.removeOptionalCharacters("+31 (0)12 3456789");
    assertEquals("+31123456789", compactPhoneNumber);
}

@Test
public void removeOptionalCharacters_HooksAroundAreaCode_ZeroIsRemoved()
{
    String compactPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.removeOptionalCharacters("+31 (012) 3456789");
    assertEquals("+31123456789", compactPhoneNumber);
}

@Test
public void removeOptionalCharacters_HooksAroundOptionalZeroWithoutCountryCode_ZeroIsNotRemoved()
{
    String compactPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.removeOptionalCharacters("(0)12 3456789");
    assertEquals("0123456789", compactPhoneNumber);
}

@Test
public void removeOptionalCharacters_HooksAroundAreaCodeWithoutCountryCode_ZeroIsNotRemoved()
{
    String compactPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.removeOptionalCharacters("(012)3456789");
    assertEquals("0123456789", compactPhoneNumber);
}
```

ps. I think these tests cover all common cases with optional zeroes. Of course there's more unittests to cover the whole thing (the 3456789 part can also include zeroes that should not be removed, and the other optional characters like - and + should not be affected either etc.), but for simplicity sake I've left them out. You'd be able to guess the rest yourself if you think about phone numbers.

Comment: What about `+31 012 3456 789` and `+30 (0)12 3456 789` numbers?

Comment: You may have better luck submitting this to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). "Feels fragile" is not really a technical *problem* per se. What you have basically works, but it could be made better.

Comment: Anubhava, what do you mean? +31 012 3456 789 is without an area code so a valid phone number or what? Maybe you can include the country for that example in your explanation? If +30 (0)12 3456 789 has 012 as area code (so the 'hooked' 0 is optional), I'd like it to become +30123456789

Comment: MarsAtomic, true that, thanks, I didn't know about code review part of the website! Because the 'best answer' would also be debatable, I won't appoint one here, only upvote if I think it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two regex-expressions. One to validate the phone number and one to normalize it, leaving out optional characters. 
Your normalization regex should contain exclusive matching groups (separated by a |). A matching group for (0) would be

```
(\(0\))
```

I'm sure there are Java APIs available to get to the individual matching groups and replace them with whatever you like.

A regex combining (0) and the other characters would be:

```
(\(0\))|([\\s()/.-])
```

Replace only the first match of the first matching group with "".
Replace all matches of the second group with ""

Or just leave your code as is. It is readable code that is self documenting. Regex expressions need documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After a night's rest, I've come up with a little simpler version of the example I provided in the question: the split regex can be used for replacing, and it's even better, because it'll replace the optional 0 for (012) area codes as well (the last hook will be replaced with all other optional characters anyway).

On top of that, my example code removed all additional zeroes in a phone number too (I think that's part of what Anubhava meant in the comment). This is also solved by my new solution:

```
private static final String OPTIONAL_ZERO_REGEX = Pattern.quote("(0");

public static String removeOptionalZero(String phoneNumber)
{
    String[] split = phoneNumber.split(OPTIONAL_ZERO_REGEX);
    if (split.length == 2 && !split[0].isEmpty())
    { // Only remove the optional zero when preceded by a country code
        return phoneNumber.replaceFirst(OPTIONAL_ZERO_REGEX, "");
    }
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

replaceFirst instead of replaceAll is a little neater, although I don't think it'll make a difference in practice.

Additional unittests to prove it works for non-optional zeroes:

```
@Test
public void removeOptionalCharacters_HooksAroundAreaCodeAndManyAdditionalZeroes_ZeroIsRemoved()
{
    String compactPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.removeOptionalCharacters("+30 (005) 0511010");
    assertEquals("+30050511010", compactPhoneNumber);
}

@Test
public void removeOptionalCharacters_HooksAroundAreaCodeWithoutCountryCodeAndManyAdditionalZeroes_ZeroIsNotRemoved()
{
    String compactPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.removeOptionalCharacters("(005)0511010");
    assertEquals("0050511010", compactPhoneNumber);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Another option:

```
private static final String OPTIONAL_ZERO = "(0";
private static final String OPTIONAL_ZERO_REGEX = Pattern.quote(OPTIONAL_ZERO);

public static String removeOptionalZero(String phoneNumber)
{
    if (phoneNumber.indexOf(OPTIONAL_ZERO) > 0)
    { // Only remove the optional zero when preceded by a country code
        return phoneNumber.replaceAll(OPTIONAL_ZERO_REGEX, "");
    }
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

ps. the last example will remove `(0` multiple times if possible. However, I don't think a case like (0031)(012)3456789 exists and the hooks are only used around (part of) the area code. If not, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Can try this though

```
([+]*)([ ])*(\w)?([\d]+)
```